# How to track IP addresses

Tags: nodes

I want to track IP address of visitors in my site using statistics module.

A log of which is attached here( 3 day log). I can't figure out if an IP address is used by a bot or human being. For example when I checked the 2nd and 3rd IP address, they turned out to be that of Google and Microsoft( Bing). But I've no idea about the first ip address with 900 visits in 3 days.

I want to track malicious user ip address for Adsense invalid clicks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What module are you using to get the list of IPs ? You need a [Reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) to integrate with your module, I wasn't able to find such module on drupal.org but there's a lot of sites that provides such service like Domain tools: [lookup for 203.153.44.130](http://whois.domaintools.com/203.153.44.130) .

Comment: No... I just need to monitor if someone is visiting frequently and causing invalid Adsense clicks for fraud activity. In short something like Statcounter monitoring functionality built in Drupal

Comment: Have you tried the [StatCounter](http://drupal.org/project/statcounter) modules ?

Comment: Currently I'm using it's free plan. It is costly. I've put up this question to see if I can save money using Drupal modules like that of Statcounter.

Comment: Can you explain in your question what StatCounter provides that you want to replicate in Drupal ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Google Analytics (or piwik if you want more privacy)?